# ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage not showing error message

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, pagerequestmanager, asyncpostbackerror

I've always used the following two bits of code (which use to work) to catch Ajax `asyncPostBackError`s.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError" />
```

and

```
protected void ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e) 
{ 
ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message; 
}
```

But now even though the unhandled exception has been caught in this event handler function and the `AsyncPostBackErrorMessage` been set with the Exception message, I'm always getting the same error reporting in the page in a alert box no matter what the exception message was, saying:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message recieved from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to the Respnse.Write() ....
```

The error is the same error you would get if you had an unhandled `asyncPostBack` exception and you didn't wire up the `Scriptmanger's` `asyncPostBackError` event handler method.

No matter what I do I get the same error. What would be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a shot in the dark, but maybe global exception handling is taking place after your `ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError` function is called. If that exception handling is doing a `server.transfer` to an error page, then the HTML sent back will not be parsable by the script manager.

This was happening on one of my sites and was solved by adding Server.ClearError() to the `ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError` function. This prevented `Global.Application_Error` function from being called.

Comment: I had this exact issue, above answer solved it for me.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that was it.  That could have taken hours to fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems i'm facing the same problem after upgrading from VS 2005 to VS 2008.
I use this code:

```
if (e.Exception is LandingPageUIExceptionInvalidMSISDN)
{
    msgresolved = "ErrorPopUpInvalidNumber";
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = msgresolved;
}
```

in order to handle the exception and display a proper error message. The `AsyncPostBackErrorMessage` is assigned properly but at client side when the following is executed in JavaScript:

```
var ErrorPopUpDivID = e.get_error().message;
alert(ErrorPopUpDivID);
```

The `ErrorPopUpDivID` is not what i had asigned to `AsyncPostBackErrorMessage`. It used to work for me too. I'll try to figure out if it might be a .NET 3.5 issue.

Finally the following 3 lines of JavaScript solved my problem:

```
var ErrorPopUpDivID = e.get_error().message;
var re = new RegExp("Sys.*: ", "g");
ErrorPopUpDivID = ErrorPopUpDivID.replace(re, "");
```