# Show error caused during patrial postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

**Is there a way to show error notification to user when error occurred during partial postback of an Update Panel?**

I have tried injecting script using `RegisterStartupScript` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock` both, but failed, I believe because partial postback is not successful therefore update panel's internal framework stop executing script, which causes my error notification script to not run. Below is the error I generated on click of a Test button, on click of which
[image]

Below is the code I'm using to inject error notification alert box for all errors caused during partial postback.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
    Entities.Exception exceptionObj = new Entities.Exception();
    Exception x = Server.GetLastError();

    if (x != null)  {
        if (x.InnerException != null)  {
            exceptionObj.Message = x.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            exceptionObj.StackTrace = x.InnerException.ToString();
        }  else  {
            exceptionObj.Message = x.Message.ToString();
            exceptionObj.StackTrace = x.ToString();
        }
    }

    Server.ClearError();

    System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
    if (page != null)  {
        RadAjaxManager MainRadAjaxManager = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(page);

        if (MainRadAjaxManager != null && MainRadAjaxManager.IsAjaxRequest)
            // didn't work
            //MainRadAjaxManager.ResponseScripts.Add(script); 

            // didn't work
            //page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Yogesh');", true);

            // didn't work
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Error Occured.');", true);
    }
}
```

*Note: I'm using Telerik's RadAjaxManager*

Comment: please check this link may be it will help you [UpdatePanel Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826008/updatepanel-exception-handling)

Comment: While the linked thread shows how to capture server exceptions on the client (and that's necessary), this will still not let the server code register your script. Consider attaching a debugger to find where the error originates and handle it so your server logic can continue.